# Алгоритм суммы произведений

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Привет! Помогите пожалуйста с создать алгоритм для суммы произведений. Должен быть цикл в цикле, первый сделал (произведение), а как теперь сюда сумму подключить? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не "произведения суммы", а "суммы произведений"

Comment: Добавьте где `m=1` еще перед ним `s=0`; где `m=(x+...` - нужно еще и `i` прибавлять, вы его забыли... а там где `help` - `s = s + m`, `i = i+1` и соответствующий ромбик... Да, и поменяйте местами `i=0` и `j=0`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Реализация, думаю, такая будет:

```
int x = 1, n = 3, sum = 0, p = 1;

 for( int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
     p = p * (x + i + j*j);
   }
   sum += p;
 }
```